# How do I change part of a URL using form input?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, slider

I am working on a site where customers can click on various buttons and input text into forms and the image of the product will change. They are also able to see multiple views of the product with a slider.

I need to be able to grab their input from the form field and replace part of the URL the product image is being called from with their input. I have included a jsfiddle of the code I am currently using.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jaysenedwinward/4pu2k4m3/1/

```
<div id="productimage">
<img id="vignette" src="http://scene7.website.com/layer/decal&src=ir{vignette=012345&color=678910&pos=1&show}" 
width="300" alt="slider images"/>
</div>
<div id="spinner">
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="180" min="0" max="370" step="45"/>
</div>
```

In the 'src' i would like to be able to use input from different forms to change the numbers for 'vignette', 'color'. I would LOVE even more for the slider to be able to change the value 'pos' in the URL too, so the current value of the slider is used in the URL as the position instead of a form.

Can you assist me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

The fiddle for this seems to have disappeared.  :(

---

If you are using jQuery this is very simple.  All you need to do is assign an onChange event to that form input in your document ready.

Then change the [`.prop('src', value)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) of the img element.

```
$("#myInput").on('change', function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    var linkModified = "http://scene7.website.com/layer/decal&src=ir{vignette="+inputValue+"&color=678910&pos=1&show}";
    $("#vignette").prop('src', linkModified);
});
```

Comment: I am trying this out right now. Thank you everyone for the quick responses.

Comment: @JaysenWard Can you mark my answer correct by clicking the checkmark to the left (under the arrows).   And also click the up arrow.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score -1):

With JavaScript you can get the values from the input fields. Based in those values you can put the source string together.

```
var sliderValue = document.getElementById('slider').value;
var colorValue = document.getElementById('color').value;

var srcString = "http://yourwebsite.com/?color=" + colorValue + "&slider=" + sliderValue;

document.getElementById('vignette').attr('src', srcString);
```

Comment: Will this code even run? You are using .attr(), a jQuery method,  with javascript.  I don't know if that even works.  Probably not.  Besides, in jQuery .attr() is deprecated and .prop() is the replacement.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right! Attr() is indeed deprecated. However jQuery should work on a JavaScript element. With an onchange event should this piece of code work fine.